# Pulling data off of a telnet connection while simultaneously running shell script

Tags: shell, telnet

I'm trying to write a test script which will access my device under test via telnet while simultaneously running a shell script which automates the other portions of my test.  The automation portion is complete, but I am having an issue properly opening a telnet connection and saving the data off of it as the test runs.

Below is my test shell script and the expect script that it is referencing

```
#! /bin/bash

declare -r telnetip=1.1.1.2
declare -r username=root
declare -r filename=telnettest.txt
declare -r runTime=10
./telnet.exp $telnetip $username $filename $runTime #telnet script
./tot.sh #automation script
```

---

```
#! /usr/bin/expect -f

set base_dir [lindex $argv 0]
set user [lindex $argv 1]
set filename [lindex $argv 2]
set delay [lindex $argv 3]

spawn telnet 
expect "telnet> "
send "open $base_dir\r"
expect "Trying 1.1.1.2..."
expect "Connected to 1.1.1.2"
expect "Escape character is '^]'. "
expect "soc1 login:"
send "$user\r"
sleep 2
expect "*$*"
send "<data access command>\r" > $filename
sleep delay+5
```

I am getting this error when I run the above:

```
usage: send [args] string
    while executing
"send "<data access command>\r" > $filename"
    (file "./telnet.exp" line 18)
```

My last foray into Unix was 14 years ago, so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong....be gentle.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing shell and expect syntax. You need:

```
log_file $filename
send "<data access command>\r"
sleep [expr {$delay+5}]
```

But your objective is unclear. Where is the "simultaneous" script?

Comment: The additional script that I want to run simultaneously while running the telnet.exp was left off the example shell script.  It would be called right after.  I edited the original post to reflect this.